# Extract all the first words after the word "Class"

Tags: java, regex

Following code returns Application aaa bbbb xxxx Ass .However I don't want to extract xxxx Ass words too. How to fix this issue?

```
public static final String EXAMPLE_TEST = "ddd with fff Node  preceded"
            + " by Class Application  bzxcd by " 
            + "Class aaa ds  preceded by Class bbbb xxxx Ass";

String pattern = ".*?Class(\\s)+(\\w+)";
System.out.println(EXAMPLE_TEST.replaceAll(pattern, "$1$2"));
```

Expected output:

```
Application aaa bbbb
```

Comment: Please reformulate your question (together with a few testcases). It is unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: This code has several typos. It's also formatted poorly. Please post code that actually compiles, runs, and demonstrates the problem. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: What is your expected output here ?

Comment: `Application aaa bbbb`

Comment: Can i do it using String array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `replaceAll` here. Use this regex:

```
"\\bClass\\s+(\\w+)\\b";
```

and use `Matcher.find()` method to get you matches like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bClass\\s+(\\w+)\\b");

Matcher m = p.matcher(EXAMPLE_TEST);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String EXAMPLE_TEST = "ddd with fff Node  preceded"
            + " by Class Application  bzxcd by " 
            + "Class aaa ds  preceded by Class bbbb xxxx Ass";


String[] str=EXAMPLE_TEST.split(" ");     

   for (int i = 0; i < str.length-1; i++) {
        if (str[i].equals("Class")){
            ++i;
            System.out.print(str[i]+" ");

        }
```

OutPut : Application aaa bbbb